# How to change stripe locale when the stripe variable has been initialized

Tags: typescript, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe in a `TypeScript` application and I've read that it's possible to set up the stripe variable with a locale like this: `var stripe = Stripe('pk_test', {locale: 'en'});` but If I want to change the language after the initialization I'm not able to do it... 
I thought to create a new instance of the stripe variable but the library says: `IntegrationError: Please use the same instance of 'Stripe' you used to create this Element to create your Source or Token.`

So what do I need to change the locale at the runtime?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there is the option to re-initialise the elements object with a new locale [0]. And then to re-mount the elements based on your new elements object, this test seems to work changing a Spanish setup into a German one [1].

`elements = stripe.elements( {locale: 'de'});`

Hope that helps!

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create#stripe_elements-options-locale

[1] https://jsfiddle.net/v3nkm4n/5uz6mrbh/20/