# How to customize Payment Element in Japanese?

Tags: stripe-payments

I recently signed up for Stripe and have successfully integrated Payment Element into my web application. However, the texts from the integrated Payment Element are displayed in English by default such as `Card number`, `Expiration`, etc. I would like to display those texts in Japanese.

I have found that, for example, `Card number` element has a `.Label` class as you can see on [Elements Appearance API](https://stripe.com/docs/elements/appearance-api?platform=web#form-inputs---labels-above) so I did the following.

```
.Label {
    font-size: 0;
}
.Label::after {
    font-size: 1rem;
    content: "カードナンバー";
}
```

This, however, did not replace `Card number` with `カードナンバー`.

Is Payment Element not available in Japanese?

Is there a way to customize Payment Element in Japanese?

If it is not possible, what other way would you suggest to collect payments in Japanese? I don't mind coding a lot as long as it works and is customizable.

Comment: The word you want is probably カード番号, by the way.

Comment: I'm not looking for a translator. I'm looking for a way to display Payment Element in Japanese.

Comment: I understand, but maybe you should also be looking for a translator, too.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61407149/how-to-change-stripe-locale-when-the-stripe-variable-has-been-initialized) on stackoverflow.

You need to set `locale` when initiating Payment Element on the client side like the following.

```
var elements = stripe.elements({
    locale: 'ja',
    // clientSecret: ...,
    // appearance: ...,
});
```